# How to simplify this query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am somewhat new to Access and I need help with a query that Access does not execute because of `Not enough space on temporary disk`.

I have one table. A product may have up to 3 IDs and a place to sell. If there is a place to sell, the name will be shown along with a combined identifier consisting of the three IDs plus the *"k1"* prefix. An example of the resulting combined identifier would be *"k1 3232 232 1231233"* (if it has three IDs).

The column names are *ProductID1*, *ProductID2*, *ProductID3*, *Place1*.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIf(IsNull([Tam_Liste]![Place1]),"","k1 " & [Tam_Liste]![ProductID1] & " " & [Tam_Liste]![ProductID2] & " " & [Tam_Liste]![ProductID3]) AS item_sku, Tam_Liste.[Place1]
FROM Tam_Liste;
```

Answer (score 1):

For every row where `Place1` is null, you are returning an empty string as `item_sku`. So without DISTINCT all such entries would be returned as

```
item_sku  Place1
--------  ------
          NULL
          NULL
          NULL
          NULL
          NULL
…         …
```

and DISTINCT condenses them to just one row. Do you need that row in the output? To me, it does not make much sense to keep it. I would get rid of it with a simple filter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  "k1 " & ProductID1 & " " & ProductID2 & " " & ProductID3 AS item_sku,
  Place1
FROM
  Tam_Liste
WHERE
  Place1 IS NOT NULL
;
```

Furthermore, I would also consider moving the concatenation bit to the front end and use the database only as a *data* source<sup>*</sup>. My final query, therefore, would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ProductID1,
  ProductID2,
  ProductID3,
  Place1
FROM
  Tam_Liste
WHERE
  Place1 IS NOT NULL
;
```

I am not 100% sure but it seems likely to me that the above query would require less temporary disk space than the original one.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>I realise that things may work differently with Access, as it can be used both as a back end and as a front end. Nevertheless, I would still keep this option in mind.</sub>

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you very much. It worked as I wished.